# Jest Testing with TypeORM

Tags: react-native, expo, typeorm, ts-jest, babel-jest

I'm trying to get Jest working with the [TypeORM Expo-Example project](https://github.com/typeorm/expo-example/blob/master/package.json)

I've done a lot to try to get either ts-jest as well as expo-jest working.  I have followed official guides for both [Jest](https://jestjs.io/docs/getting-started) and [Expo Jest](https://docs.expo.dev/guides/testing-with-jest/).  I was able to expo init a new empty project (not the TypeORM example) and get Expo-Jest working as expected, but when I to apply the changes to the TypeORM expo project, it ran into issues.

I think expo-jest is preferred.  It will probably be easier to start from a clean clone of the TypeORM Expo-Example repo.

I've edited the package.json to a version that shouldn't have dependency issues if it is an easier starting point. (the jest stuff can be modified or removed in favor of separate config)

```html
{
  "name": "expo-example",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.18.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.18.0",
    "@types/jest": "^27.5.1",
    "@types/node": "^10.1.3",
    "@types/react": "~17.0.21",
    "@types/react-native": "~0.67.6",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^16.0.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-typescript-metadata": "^0.3.2",
    "jest": "27",
    "jest-expo": "^45.0.1",
    "react-native-typescript-transformer": "^1.2.9",
    "react-test-renderer": "17",
    "typescript": "^4.6.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start --dev-client",
    "eject": "expo eject",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "test": "jest",
    "postinstall": "patch-package"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo",
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "ts",
      "tsx",
      "js"
    ],
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(js)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
      "\\.(ts|tsx)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/ts-jest/preprocessor.js"
    },
    "testRegex": "(/__tests__/.*|\\.(test|spec))\\.(ts|tsx|js)$",
    "testPathIgnorePatterns": [
      "\\.snap$",
      "<rootDir>/node_modules/"
    ],
    "cacheDirectory": ".jest/cache",
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/(?!((jest-)?react-native|@react-native(-community)?)|expo(nent)?|@expo(nent)?/.*|@expo-google-fonts/.*|react-navigation|@react-navigation/.*|@unimodules/.*|unimodules|sentry-expo|native-base|react-native-svg)"
    ]
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "27",
    "expo": "^45.0.0",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.15.1",
    "expo-sqlite": "~10.2.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.3.0",
    "patch-package": "^6.4.7",
    "postinstall-postinstall": "^2.1.0",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.68.1",
    "react-native-sqlite-storage": "^4.1.0",
    "react-native-web": "0.17.7",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "ts-jest": "27",
    "tslib": "^1.9.1",
    "typeorm": "^0.3.6"
  }
}
```

Comment: It will help a lot if you can post the errors you've gotten and what you've tried

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, my problem is an error when i try test the return of getConnection() typeorm function or DataSource({...}).initialize() with expo-sqlite driver... to make it work i use slite3 lib instead expo-sqlite... so it work, see: https://github.com/EmanuelVogt/expo-sqlite-typeorm-jest

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).